# How to disable lisp-interaction when starting Emacs?

Tags: start-up, scratch-buffer

When I open Emacs, the `*scratch*` buffer is in Lisp Interaction mode, but I don't want that.  How can I make the buffer have a text mode instead of Lisp Interaction?

Comment: Note that for 99.99% of the users, the major mode of `*scratch*` is completely irrelevant because they never ever use that buffer.  So my crystal ball tells me that this is an X/Y question where the answer is to use another buffer (one which will automatically have the mode you need) rather than try and change the mode used in the `*scratch*` buffer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can [customize](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) the value of `initial-major-mode`, which defaults to `lisp-interaction-mode`.  Here's the variable's docstring:

> `initial-major-mode` is a variable defined in `startup.el`.
>   Its value is `lisp-interaction-mode`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Major mode command symbol to use for the initial `*scratch*` buffer.
>
> You can customize this variable.

For the customize interface you can follow the link from <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `initial-major-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>, or use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `initial-major-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> to get there directly.

Alternatively you could put something like this in your init file:

```el
(setq initial-major-mode 'text-mode)
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than changing the mode of an Emacs stalwart *Scratch*, configure initial-buffer-choice.

C-h v initial-buffer-choice